# Change UI with change in WebView URL

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview

I want to change a navigation bar selection based on the URL I receive. But I'm not able to use data binding inside the code. I'm using this inside an Activity. How do I change UI here?

```
private class MyWebClient : WebViewClient() {

        override fun doUpdateVisitedHistory(view: WebView?, url: String?, isReload: Boolean) {
            if (url.toString().contains("demo.example.com/discover")) {
                // UI binding code here
            }
            super.doUpdateVisitedHistory(view, url, isReload)
        }

        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
            view: WebView?,
            request: WebResourceRequest?
        ): Boolean {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request)
        }
    }
```

I tried creating other methods references, but unable to access those methods here